# Connect to Raspberry Pi from iPad via Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, display

I'm considering experimenting with a Raspberry Pi. I was wondering if I could connect to the Raspberry Pi from my iPad via Bluetooth and use the iPad as a screen that way. In my head it makes sense. Just not sure if it can actually be done.

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi's Stack Exchange! Do you intend on running the Raspbian Desktop Operating System or Raspbian Lite, which only features a command-line interface? Please edit your question and clarify this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rapsberry pi is remotely connectable from any device. Unfortunately, due to the way bluetooth works, you can not have very large streams of data being passed over it which is a live feed of what you raspberry pi is outputting. The best way to connect to a pi and get a similar experience with GUI is to use VNC server on the Pi and connect to the Pi with with a VNC client on your iPad. The easiest way to do this is to create a wireless access point using your Pi (Wifi network) and connect to that network. You will need to have WiFi or ethernet to connect to internet and Pi, but Bluetooth is not capable of that.